# Whitening a regression with an AR process

Tags: autoregressive, white-noise

I was reading a research paper:

$Y_{t}\text{=}\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X_{1t}+\beta_{2}X_{2t}$
(where $Y_{t}$ is stock returns and not the change in stock returns)
($X{}_{1t}$ is the return of a stock market index and $X_{2t}$ is the return of a bond index)
They think $X_{2t}$ follows an AR(3) process and they mention two things in the paper that I want to inquire about:
1- They mentioning that the results with and without whitening are similar
2- They mention that the interest rate series is the residual of the AR(3) process.
My question is the following : how did they whiten the process?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the name of the paper as its quite hard to tell from the problem at hand. One way they could have done this is to include three lags of $X_{2}$.

Comment: I am still stuck on the same topic despite investing many days on it. I am shocked by the lack of details in statistics textbooks. The paper that I referred to is by Flannery and James (Journal of Finance 1984). In general if Yt=β0+β1X1t+β2X2t and X2 follows an AR(3) process . How would we prewhiten the series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you are talking abour the article: “The Effect of Interest Rate Changes on the Common Stock Returns of Financial Institutions”. I further expect that you have some working knowledge of ARIMA estimation and model fitting. If not, please let me know and I will elaborate on my answer.

We have equation (2) in their article which they want to estimate: ${Y_{t}\text{=}\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X_{1t}+\beta_{2}X_{2t}+\varepsilon_{t}}
 $ where $Y_{t}
 $, $X_{1t}
 $ and $X_{2t}
 $ are interest rate indices. They say on p. 1145: “If these three interest rates indices measure unanticipated changes in the interest rates, then the series should be white noise processes.” They test this by looking at the ACF, PACF and the Ljung-Box Q statistics of each of these three series and find that there is autocorrelation in the series, hence they are not white noise which is neccessary if these series measure unanticipated changes in the interest rate. They then write on p. 1146: “To obtain a measure of unanticipated interest rate changes, a third-order autoregressive model AR(3) was estimated for each series." Here they fit an AR(3) model for each of thes series. Note that if the series are adequately represented by the AR(3) the residual of this series should be white noise! They essentially estimate these three equations and save the fitted residuals:

$Y_{t}=\delta+\theta_{1}Y_{t-1}+\theta_{2}Y_{t-2}+\theta_{3}Y_{t-3}+u_{t};\; u_{t}\sim N\left(0,\,\sigma^{2}\right)
 $

$X_{1t}=\delta+\theta_{1}X_{1t-1}+\theta_{2}X_{1t-2}+\theta_{3}X_{1t-3}+v_{t};\; v_{t}\sim N\left(0,\,\sigma^{2}\right)
 $

$X_{2t}=\delta+\theta_{1}X_{2t-1}+\theta_{2}X_{2t-2}+\theta_{3}X_{2t-3}+w_{t};\; w_{t}\sim N\left(0,\,\sigma^{2}\right)
 $

What this means is that all the saved residuals from the fitted series are white noise. The then use the residuals of these three series as the interest rate indices as they are white noise and hence: “If these three interest rates indices measure unanticipated changes in the interest rates, then the series should be white noise processes.” (p. 1145). Essentially they estimate equation (2) with $Y_{t}=u_{t}
 $, $X_{1t}=v_{t}
 $ and $X_{2t}=w_{t}
 $, rather then to use the origianl interest indices they use the residuals from the AR(3) model they fitted for each series. This is how they make the series white noise or “whiten” it as they say.

What they mention in footnote 10 is more like a robustness test: “Equation (2) was also estimated without whitening the interest rate series. The results obtained are virtually identical to the results reported in Sections III and IV.” What they do here is to estimate equation (2) with the original interest indices!

The whitened regression: $u_{t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}v_{t}+\beta_{2}w_{t}+error_{t}
 $

The un-whitened regression $Y_{t}\text{=}\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X_{1t}+\beta_{2}X_{2t}+\varepsilon_{t}
 $

Comment: Thanks Dan. If this is the case the answer is clear. What confused me is the textbook of Bisgaard and Kulahci "TIME SERIES ANALYSIS
AND FORECASTING BY EXAMPLE". They use a single linear regression model and they say that Y should be whitened using the AR coefficients of the AR(3) model of x (chapter 8, page 207). It was confusing especially with the presence of a second independent variable. Anyway thanks a million.

Comment: You might be referring to the same method as in Bisgaard and Kulahci 's textbook. Are the coefficient of the AR(3) model the same in the 3 AR models? in other words are thetas of AR(r) for the interest rate series used to estimate the residuals of the dependent variable and the other independent variable?

Comment: You're welcome! Bisgaard and Kulahci's write: "This involves filtering the output data through the same model with the same coefficient estimates that we fitted to the input data." (bottom, p. 209). This is not the same as the article you were referring to. In Table 2, p. 1147 you can see the coefficients in the estimated AR(3) model for every series. They estimate a new model for each series so its not the same coefficient estimates in the article, nor the same approach (although similar)!